# How can I make a two textviews wrap content while maintaining a maximum length?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm working on a chat function where I want the users messages appear on the *right side* and messages from others on the *left side*. The *right side* is giving some trouble.

As the message is short, it should stick to the right side of the screen, then the name of the user should be right next to it as shown below (Android developers "*show layout bounds*" is on):

[image: The layout as it should appear with short messages]

Just some simple **`LinearLayout`** with two `TextView`s aligned to the right, but you can see this doesn't work with longer messages, as they are clipped off and the name is often invisible at all. I've managed to do this with a constraint layout:

[image: ConstraintLayout solution, works for long messages but doesn't make short one stick to the screens edge]]

The **`ConstraintLayout`** (wrapper) has a 100dp constraint to the left for the margin and within it, the name and the message are chained. The downside is that short messages don't stick to the right anymore.

> How do I manage the layout to automatically align the way I want?

Comment: Put code of your layout for we will can help you...

Comment: You should use Relative Layout for that purpose or use FrameLayout and set gravity to Right

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you, if you already have a `ConstraintLayout`, play a little bit more with the possible constraint attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/name"
      style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
      android:paddingEnd="8dp"
      android:text="Name"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/message"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/message"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
      android:text="Message"
      app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/name"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/name2"
      style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
      android:paddingEnd="8dp"
      android:text="Name"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/message2"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/message"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/message2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
      android:text="A Very Long message for you to read  set we cen test to row breaking in this text Message"
      app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/name2"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/message"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The magic is: `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` which takes care about the maximum width of the view, depending on the surrounding views (simply constraint with toStartOf ... EndOf)(see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout).

Also `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"` takes care, that the views always alligned to the maximum left and right, this is Chaining in constraint layouts (https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)

[image]

Hope it helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: Hmm, that already looks good indeed. Can you also tell me how I can stick the name of the user to the message? The bottom message behaves as I'd like it to, but with the first one, there's a gap between the users name and the message I'd like to avoid (it should be like in my first picture).

Comment: Use "app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed" instead of spread inside. And add a horizontal bias of 1 for the chain.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manage this functionality by implementing the `constraint` `Guideline`.

With this, you can split your entire layout vertically and separate user messages and responses while formatting each side individually.

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/guideline"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
```

Try using something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

<LinearLayout
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline"
    android:id="@+id/friend_column"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Friend"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="Whats up?"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/friend_column"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline"
    android:id="@+id/user_column"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="User"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="I'm sailing away set an open course for the virgin sea
        I've got to be free free to face the life that's ahead of me
        On board I'm the captain so climb aboard
        We'll search for tomorrow on every shore
        And I'll try oh Lord I'll try to carry on"/>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Then how would I make sure short messages stick to the right side of the screen?

Comment: @AxelKöhler Maybe my updated answer can give you an idea.  Including your layout file could also help users offer better answers.

Comment: I see where you're going, but in that case, the own messages (or rather the LinearLayout that wraps them) should be constrained right (so the guideline is not necessary), which is the 'solution' I'd already tried. The only difference would be you using the property `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent`, which my Android Studio refuses to compile (it only knows `_default`, `_max` and `_min`). Any solution for that?

Comment: Make sure that you're implementing the latest constraint layout `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'`